# PHP/REGEX - Changing values of INSERT in sql file

Tags: php, regex

I have a sql file that contains 2 million queries, The problem is one the column have incorrect value for each record, So i wanna change the value of INSERT query with the correct one (i have a txt file for fix)

You may ask why I don't use regular UPDATE query, Well, It cost 80% of my hard I/O for each query (Windows/XAMPP)

`threads.sql`:

```
INSERT INTO `threads` (`id`, `thread_id`, `user_id`, `title`, `body`, `sent_at`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `category_id`) VALUES
(1, 69872, 1, 'thread title', 'thread body', '2006-08-21 20:30:00', '2020-05-11 14:30:37', '2020-05-11 14:30:37', 2),
(2, 358454, 1, 'thread title 2', 'thread body 2', '2020-05-04 19:30:00', '2020-05-11 14:30:41', '2020-05-11 14:30:41', 2),
(3, 337188, 1, 'thread title 3', 'thread body 3', '2017-03-02 20:30:00', '2020-05-11 14:30:44', '2020-05-11 14:30:44', 2),
```

The target is `thread_id` and `user_id` , only `user_id` should update with new value look at this text file that i told you which have correct value:

`fixes.txt` :

```
69872 => 67
358454 => 22
337188 => 15
```

It means the `thread_id` with value of 69872 belongs to a `user_id` with id of 67, But in sql file this is 1, So i tried this script:

```php
$sql = file_get_contents('threads.sql');

$proper = file('fixes.txt', 2);

foreach($proper as $line){
    $line = explode('=>', $line);
    $threadId = trim($line[0]);
    $userId = trim($line[1]);
    $replaced = preg_replace("/INSERT INTO `threads` \([\s\S]*?\(\d+, $threadId, (\d+),/", "$0$userId$2",$sql);
    $lines .= $replaced;
}

file_put_content('fixed.sql', $lines);
```

My regex captures the target but i don't know why the script doesn't work

[Demo Regex](https://regex101.com/r/wdvlNi/1)

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is the regex not matching? Dose the SQL query return with error? Try to remove the non-relevant data, and add: what do you expect, and what happens instead.

Comment: My regex works (in regex101.com)  but the `$lines` variable doesnt contains the replacements

Comment: What *does* `$lines` contain after the loop? It's hard to debug your code without having access to the actual files. Try to see what is the content of `$replaced` inside each iteration (using a debugger or temporary prints). Is that the expected value? Also consider initializing `$lines` to an empty string before the loop.

Comment: I did: var_dump($replaced); it prints NULL

Comment: Great, you have a first clue. Now you know you have a problem at the `preg_replace` already (according to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)). Try [preg_last_error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-last-error.php) for further investigation.